# How do I cancel/replace one element of running `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && ...` chain?

Tags: shell, jobs

```
$ command1 && command2 && command3
Running command1 ...
Running command2 ...^Z
[1]+  Stopped
$ fg && command4 && wrong_command5 && command6
Running command3
Running command4
```

How do I cancel the `wrong_command5`, scheduling `right_command5` instead after the termination of currently running `command4`?

Comment: Note: this is not an urgent question.

Comment: Did you mean to say `command4 && wrong_command5` (two ampersands)?

Comment: @MichaelHomer, Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `command4` is currently running, it is possible to do this pretty straightforwardly:

```
^Z
$ fg && right_command5 && command6
```

This is essentially what you were already doing to start `command4` in the first place. `wrong_command5` and the rest will be replaced and never execute.

I think that behaviour is going to be unexpected to you, so read on for an explanation of where things don't work the way you thought they would.

---

However: note that **your original command sequence does not do what you think it does**. When you do:

```
$ command1 && command2 && command3
Running command1 ...
Running command2 ...^Z
[1]+  Stopped
$ fg && command4
```

then `command2` will be resumed, *but the rest of the chain will not be*. Stopping `command2` with <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> means that it exits abnormally with `SIGTSTP` (-20). Since `command2` exits non-succesfully, `&&` short-circuits out of the chain and `command3` will never run. `command4` will start immediately after the end of the resumed `command2`.

You can watch this behaviour in action by replacing the `&&` with `||`:

```
$ command2 || echo Running command3, exit was $?
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 command2
Running command3, exit was 148
$
```

You have to list out the entire subsequent chain of commands when you resume if you want the behaviour you're aiming for. Alternatively, if you want to be able to stop and resume whole command chains you need to run them in a subshell:

```
$ (command1 && command2 && command3)
^Z
$ fg
```

In that case, though, there's no way to intercede and replace a command at all.

Comment: `In that case, though, there's no way to intercede and replace a command at all.` -> I expect I can suspend the the chain, analyse what is currently being executed, then `kill -9` the subshell, than resume execution, appending corrected remainder of the chain.

Comment: Note: asked another question about `&&` chains and jobs: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151376/how-do-i-gracefully-suspend-and-resume-cmd1-cmd2-cmd3-chain

Answer (score 1):

*(This answers an earlier version of the question, which was pretty different due to the omission of one character. The second command was `fg && command4 & wrong_command5 && command6` originally, and it turned out that it was really meant as `fg && command4 && wrong_command5 && command6`. This answers the old question with the background command, see other answers for the new question variant)*

---

The command that you want to cancel is running in the foreground, and it is also "chained" with the next command by `&&`. If it behaves nicely on `^C` and exits with non-zero status, all is fine:

To simplify the examples, I will split this line:

```
$ fg && command4 & wrong_command5 && command6
```

into the equivalent lines:

```
$ fg && command4 & 
$ wrong_command5 && command6
```

We need to exit the foreground program `wrong_command5`, and can do so easily with `^C`.
Then, we list the background jobs to see which one we want to wait for.
The job id is used with the builtin command `wait` to wait for the job to terminate.
We use the `wait` as the start of the list which runs the replacement command, and then the following command previously used.

```
$ command1 && command2 && command3
Running command1 ...
Running command2 ...^Z
[1]+  Stopped
$ fg && command4 & 
$ wrong_command5 && command6
^C
$ jobs
[1]  - running    command3
[2]  + running    command4
$ wait %2 && right_command5 && command6
```

If `wrong_command5` does not behave nicely on getting a `^C` from keyboard, but on some other signal, you can use `kill` instead of `^C` like this:

```
$ fg && command4 & 
$ wrong_command5 && command6
[1] 14407
^Z
[2]  + 14408 suspended  wrong_command5
$ jobs
[1]  - running    command3
[2]  + running    command4
[3]    suspended  wrong_command5
$ kill %2
[2]  + 14408 terminated  wrong_command5
$ wait %2 && right_command5 && command6
```

Comment: The question was a bit wrong: it supposed to have double `&&` everywhere. And I need to unschedule `wrong_command5` without disrupting currently running `command4`.

Comment: Hmm... that's pretty different. I thought about whether you mean it that way, but the `&` did make sense somehow...

Comment: With `&` the wrong command gets executed immediately, so I can find a PID and cancel it.

Comment: Ah... did I get it right: `command4` is running, and you want to let if finish normally, but make `wrong_command5` not start after `command4`? Makes even more sense, interesting question :)

Comment: Ok, I read the other answer, that's good... so this answer just stopped to make sense :) Do you see any reason to keep it? (I would need to add an explanation why I use the older command variant of course)

Comment: I don't know. You can add a notice to the beginning that it answers other question, to prevent confusion.