# How do I gracefully suspend and resume `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` chain?

Tags: bash, jobs

From the [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151285/how-do-i-cancel-replace-one-element-of-running-cmd1-cmd2-cmd3-cha) it seems I failed to understand how `&&` and `^Z` interact properly:

```
$ command1 && command2 && command3
Running command1 ...
Running command2 ...^Z
[1]+  Stopped
$ fg && command4
Running command3
Running command4
```

, which I thought can be used to "append" the chain after it started, seemed to work only because of `command3` was the last command; and stopping it on `command2`, for example, whould have provided different result (`command3` whould have been ignored).

How do I suspend the `&&` chain gracefully, without cancelling the rest of the commands? I want also the exit code to be preserved if it is needed for further logic in the command line.

If I know that I may want to suspend the chain in advance, I can start it like that: `( command1 && command2 && command3 )`, so it whould be gracefully suspendable. Buw how do I do it when it is started plainly?

If the commands don't provide output (unlike in example above), should not be run twice or out of order then the only way I can think up is pressing `^Z`, analysing what was stopped, then manually constructing `fd && the_rest_of_commands`, which is inconvenient and error-prone.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misinterpreting what's happening. When you do:

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

The shell starts `cmd1` in a child process, waits for that process, and then starts `cmd2` if `cmd1` exited with a zero exit status.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, the wait returns, the shell sets `$?` to 148 for instance (128 + SIGTSTP), and the evaluation of the rest is done *at that point*, so `cmd2` is *not* executed. And `cmd1` becomes a background job.

Had you typed:

```
cmd1 || cmd2
```

Or:

```
cmd1; cmd2
```

`cmd2` would have been executed **upon <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>** and you'd have had to wait for it to finish to get the next prompt (where you can `fg` or `bg` your background job).

In `zsh`, when you press <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> in:

```
{cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3}
```

That suspends the whole group (and moves it to a subshell). However, upon resume, the suspended command, when it terminates will set `$?` to 20 regardless of its exit status and I don't think there's a way around that, so you end up with the same behavior (though in `{cmd1 || cmd2}` cmd2 would be executed after cmd1 has finished instead of straight on the <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>).

Comment: `Had you typed` doesn't suid. I could have typed `(cmd1 && cmd2)` if I cared in advance. Also I don't want other commands to be executed in case of failure.

Comment: When I press Ctrl+Z I usually don't want some action to be automatically started...

Comment: @Vi. I agree the behavior is less than ideal, but it's the way it is. In that regard, the `(t)csh` behavior (where job control comes from) is better IMO: CTRL-Z discards the other actions on the command line.

Comment: Why does ksh behave differently (`sleep 1 && sleep 2` executes `sleep 2` if you press Ctrl+Z during `sleep 1`)? What does POSIX have to say?

Comment: @Gilles, `sleep` is builtin in ksh93 and mksh. Use `/bin/sleep` for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like suspending the currently running component with `gdb -p` provices graceful pause, unlike `kill -STOP`.

So if you know that `command2` is currently being executed, you can do:

```
gdb -p $(pgrep -f 'command2')
```

from other terminal to suspend, then exit or continue GDB to resume.

Answer (score 0):

You can suspend the parent shell - the interactive shell you where starting the commands in:

Print the PID before you run the commands, (or find the pid later, see below):

```
$ echo $$
1234
```

From another terminal, you can stop the whole command list by suspending the interactive shell - the list consists of child processes of the interactive shell:

```
$ kill -STOP 1234
```

And continue the command list with:

```
$ kill -CONT 1234
```

As it's an important part of your use case that there are no preparations (like `echo $$`) required before running the command list, here is how you get the PID of the shell you want to stop when the list is already running in foreground.

The idea is to find the PID of the parent process of any of the commands in the list:

First, we use `pgrep` to find the PID of the currently running command. Finding the PID of any of them is enough, as only one runs at a time:

```
$ pgrep 'command1|command2|command3'
```

If `command1` etc are not really the command name of the process - that is, the first word of the command line - you need to add the `-f` option (and use `-a` for experimenting to see more than just the PID):

```
$ pgrep -f 'command1|command2|command3'
```

Then, we use `ps` to find the parent PID of the command:

```
$ ps -o ppid=
```

Combined, we get the PID of the shell to suspend like this:

```
$ pid=$(ps -o ppid= $(pgrep 'command1|command2|command3'))
```

Alltogether:

```
$ kill -STOP $(ps -o ppid= $(pgrep 'command1|command2|command3'))
$ kill -CONT $(ps -o ppid= $(pgrep 'command1|command2|command3'))
```

Comment: Why by `kill -STOP 1234` the currently executing command gets stopped? Shouldn't it only stop the shell, continuing the command (and stop&waiting only before the next command need to be executed)?

Comment: BTW I found out that `gdb -p PID` suspends the process more gracefully rather than `kill -CONT`...

Comment: Regarding why stopping the parent stops the children too: I think that kill, or the shell, will send the signal to the whole process group, as it happens in other cases. At least it worked with a simple test. I'll try to find a reference. (Btw, in which way is `gdb -p PID` more graceful?)

Comment: @Vi. Yes, that's exactly right as you describe: the `kill -STOP 1234` stops only the shell. When using `^Z` in the shell, the process group gets signaled. But not with `kill -STOP`... Hmm... need to do some cleanup...

Comment: I though about `kill -STOP -1234` (for the whole process group), but can it starle the shell (when resumed again), so it cancels the rest?

Comment: Oh, yes - `kill -STOP -1234` probably does what I expected `kill -STOP 1234` would do... I just tried to use it on a list of `sleep` - not sure, I have a hard time to understand which processes are in which process group. Could be that the command list `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3` get's it's wn group.